# c++ error in my thread constructor passing the function

Tags: multithreading, function, class, c++11

I'm trying to make a thread every time a call a function from a class, but i can't pass the function correctly:

file.h

```
#include <thread>

class Class
{
public:
    Class(int a);
    void ThreadBase(void (*func));
    int CreateThread(void (*func));
};
```

file.cpp

```
#include <thread>
Class::Class(int a)
{
    /**
     *  ...
     */
}

void Class:ThreadBase(void (*func))
{
    while(1)
    {
        /**
         *  ...
         */
    }
}

int Class:CreateThread(void (*func))
{
    std::thread th(Class::ThreadBase, func);
}
```

Error:

```
error: reference to non-static member function must be called
```

Answer (score 0):

CreateThread should call std::thread with a function and arguments for the function.

The problem is here:

```
std::thread th(Class::ThreadBase, func);
```

Class::ThreadBase is not a static function; so it can't be called directly. In this case; CreateThread should call the member function "ThreadBase" of 'this.'